# Send requests made via Nginx directly to an Angular routing component

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm having problems with setting up nginx and angular together in my MEAN app.

My application is containerized, where I have an nginx container, angular container, express container etc.

Currently, I have a location in my development.conf for each possible angular route however, now I'm adding in querys to my URLs and so I want every request made to be handled directly by my angular router.

Below are some snippets of code I have which might help clear up what I'm doing.

My angular router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'x/:field', component: XComponent },
  { path: 'y/:field', component: YComponent },
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
    ),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.8-alpine
COPY development.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Nginx development.conf file

```
upstream angular_domain {
    server angular:4200;
}
server {
    listen 80;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://angular_domain/;
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
     }
}
```

I've been trying different strategies, however in most examples I've found, nginx uses a try_files section to try and find index.html and since I'm running these in different containers, I don't believe this is possible?

Any help on how I'd go about getting this working would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ShawnC. using the above example, I don't even get an nginx 404 error, just a general page not found. Using the try_files logic, I'll get an nginx 404/500 error depending on the query passed in